# Serializing Java Path with kotlinx.serialization

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

With kotlinx.serialization, this code will throw an error:
`println(Json.encodeToString(Path.of("value")))`
saying `kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'WindowsPath' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'Path'.`

WindowsPath is internal, therefore I can not register it as a polymorphic subclass (as in [this example](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/guide/example/example-poly-08.kt)), only with Path itself, and even a custom KSerializer for Path throws the same exact error.
Is there any way to have Path properly serialize/deserialize without having to store it as a string?

Comment: >even a custom KSerializer for Path throws the same exact error

Could you share code of your custom serializer? Explicit passing it into `encodeToString` should work `println(Json.encodeToString(MyCustomPathSerializer, Path.of("value")))`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Yi4c0h5R  
Here is an example. Yes, specifying encoder directly in encodeToString works, however I am not sure how to go around parsing it when path is nested inside data classes ("InnerObject" in this example - it just does not compile) apart from writing a custom serializer for the entire data class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Path` is an interface, so it's implicitly serializable with the PolymorphicSerializer strategy. This strategy requires you to register serializers for subclasses implementing it, but as you know, in this case it's impossible.
There is a [default polymorphic serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#default-polymorphic-type-handler-for-deserialization), but it affects only deserialization process and it works only when deserializable value is a JSONObject.

And for the following serializer

```kotlin
object PathAsStringSerializer : KSerializer<Path> {
    override val descriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("Path", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Path) = encoder.encodeString(value.toAbsolutePath().toString())

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Path = Path.of(decoder.decodeString())
}
```

```
\\Not working
val module = SerializersModule { polymorphicDefault(Path::class) { PathAsStringSerializer } }
val decoded : Path = Json { serializersModule = module }.decodeFromString("C:\\Temp")
```

it will throw runtime exception `kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject as the serialized body of kotlinx.serialization.Polymorphic<Path>, but had class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonLiteral`

So, it can't be serialized in a common way, and there are 3 cases of its serialization/deserialization, which need to be handled:

### **1. Serialization of simple `Path` variable**

In this case you need to explicitly pass your custom serializer:

```kotlin
val path = Path.of("C:\\Temp")

val message1 = Json.encodeToString(PathAsStringSerializer, path).also { println(it) }
println(Json.decodeFromString(PathAsStringSerializer, message1))
```

### **2. Serialization of classes, which use `Path` as a generic parameter**

In this case you need to define separate serializers (you may reference original `PathAsStringSerializer`) and also explicitly pass them:

```kotlin
object ListOfPathsAsStringSerializer : KSerializer<List<Path>> by ListSerializer(PathAsStringSerializer)

val message2 = Json.encodeToString(ListOfPathsAsStringSerializer, listOf(path)).also { println(it) }
println(Json.decodeFromString(ListOfPathsAsStringSerializer, message2))
```

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Box<T>(val item: T)
object BoxOfPathSerializer : KSerializer<Box<Path>> by Box.serializer(PathAsStringSerializer)

val message3 = Json.encodeToString(BoxOfPathSerializer, Box(path)).also { println(it) }
println(Json.decodeFromString(BoxOfPathSerializer, message3))
```

### **3. Serialization of classes, which have fields of aforementioned types**

In this case you need to add respectful `@Serializable(with = ...)` annotations for these fields:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class InnerObject(
    @Serializable(with = ListOfPathsAsStringSerializer::class)
    val list: MutableList<Path> = mutableListOf(),
    @Serializable(with = PathAsStringSerializer::class)
    val path: Path,
    @Serializable(with = BoxOfPathSerializer::class)
    val box: Box<Path>
)
```

Or just [list them once for a whole file](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#specifying-serializers-for-a-file):

```kotlin
@file: UseSerializers(PathAsStringSerializer::class, ListOfPathsAsStringSerializer::class, BoxOfPathSerializer::class)
```

Plugin-generated serializer for this case would be good enough:

```kotlin
val message4 = Json.encodeToString(InnerObject(mutableListOf(path), path, Box(path))).also { println(it) }
println(Json.decodeFromString<InnerObject>(message4))
```