# Does Kotlin can serialize class reference information?

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

I try serialize KClass reference through standard kotlinx serialization library, but it seems completely not working with reflection stuff.

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class SocketDto(val eventType: KClass<out Event>)
    
interface Event
    
@Serializable
data class EnableEvent(val enable: Boolean) : SocketEvent
```

And after run

```kotlin
println(Json.encodeToString(SocketDto(EnableEvent::class)))
```

got

```kotlin
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'ClassReference' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'KClass'
```

Comment: Why do you need to serialise a `KClass` in the first place? That is a weird thing to serialise.

Comment: @Sweeper I need to get event type in SocketDto. Whatever. The question is much wider

Comment: `KClass` is an interface and `ClassReference` is a part of internal stdlib API, so this question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66355506/serializing-java-path-with-kotlinx-serialization/66492122

Answer (score 0):

Ok custom serializers seem to work here

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class SocketDto(
    @Serializable(with = ClassRefSerializer::class) val eventType: KClass<out Event>
)

object ClassRefSerializer : KSerializer<KClass<out Any>> {

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("classRef", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder) = Class.forName(decoder.decodeString()).kotlin

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: KClass<out Any>) = encoder.encodeString(value.jvmName)
}
```

```
{"eventType":"test.EnableEvent"}
SocketDto(eventType=class test.EnableEvent)
```

Why do not this behavior by default?

Comment: It would only work on JVM.